# Is there have a protocol for Launcher to start Data Sense and Storage Sense?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to start some build-in Apps from my app, likes Data Sense or Storage Sense, can I do it on WP8.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are currently no URI schemes for launching Data Sense or Storage Sense. You can see a list of the supported schemes for launching built-in apps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662937%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).